# Show that $(a_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence in this metric space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

**Context**

The metric space $(ℓ_0, d)$, where $$ℓ_0 = \left\{(a_n) : a_n ∈ \mathbb{R}\text{ for each } n,\text { and } (a_n)\text{ is eventually zero} \right\}$$ and

$d: ℓ_0 \times ℓ_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by $$d(a, b)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|a_n-b_n|},\text{ where } a = (a_n) \text{ and } b=(b_n)$$

Let $p$ be a prime and let $(a_k)$ be the sequence of points in $ℓ_0$ given by $$a_k=\left\{\frac{1}{p},\frac{1}{p^2},\frac{1}{p^3},...,\frac{1}{p^k},0,0,0,...\right\}\text{ for } k\in \mathbb{N}$$

(i) Calculate $d(a_{10}, a_9)$

> $$\frac{1}{p^{10}}$$

(ii)  Find $d(a_{k+1}, a_k)$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$

> $$\frac{1}{p^{k+1}}$$

**My question and attempt**

(iii) Hence show that $(a_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

> $$|a_k-a_{k-n}|=|(a_{k-n}-a)+(a_{k-n+1}-a)+...+(a_{k+1}-a)+(a_k-a)|$$ 
>   $\text {then due to the triangle inequality for modulus:}$
>   $$|a_k-a_{k-n}|\leq|a_{k-n}-a|+|a_{k-n+1}-a|+...+|a_{k+1}-a|+|a_k-a|$$
>   $\text { then because the limit } a \text{ is zero}$
>   $$|a_k-a_{k-n}|\leq|a_{k-n}|+|a_{k-n+1}|+...+|a_{k+1}|+|a_k|$$
>   $$|a_k-a_{k-n}|\leq \sum_{n}{\frac{1}{p^n}}$$
>   $$|a_k-a_{k-n}|\leq \frac{p^{-1}(1-(p^{-1})^n)}{1-p^{-1}}$$
>   $$|a_k-a_{k-n}|\leq \frac{p^{-1}-p^{-(n+1)}}{1-p^{-1}}$$
>   $$|a_k-a_{k-n}|\leq \frac{p^n-1}{p-1}$$
>   $\text{From here I would say we can always choose a } k,m \geq \mathbb{N}\text{ where } m=k-n \text{ so that }$ $$|a_k-a_{k-n}|\leq \frac{p^n-1}{p-1} \leq \frac{p^{\mathbb{N}}-1}{p-1}$$

I'm struggling greatly with how to present this especially with notation, if the logic of my answer is even correct in the first place.  I would appreciate any critiques or corrections.

Comment: There is a confusion because of notations. $(a_k)_k$ is a sequence in $(l_0,d)$. You cannot use absolute value here, but $d$, you have to prove $d(a_m,a_n)\to 0$ for $(m,n)>n_0$ or if $n_0=k$ you can as well show $d(a_k,a_{k+n})\to 0$. I don't know why you take index $k-n$ it makes no sense. If you want to use triangular inequality you have to show $d$ verifies it first (as well as $d$ being a distance, if you want to conclude it is Cauchy). Finally instead of having the sum of $1/p^k$ starting from $1$ just have the remainder sum from $k$ to $k+n$ which this time goes to  $0$.

Comment: @zwim Thanks for your response.  The reason I thought I could use absolute value was because it was in the definition of the metric, so thanks for correcting that.  Would you mind clarifying what you mean by 'If you want to use triangular inequality you have to show d verifies it first'?  I thought it was one of the axioms of a metric.  Asides from that I'll head back to the drawing board.

Comment: $d$ was given to you, but it is nowhere stated it is a distance, you have to verify it explicitly. You are right to say that "$(l_0,d)$ is a metric" space, can imply that $d$ is a distance, but I would be very suspicious whether in an exercise it is or not my duty to prove it. In doubt, I would go for the proof.

Comment: @zwim I thought a metric was a distance function by definition?  On a separate note, do you think I should delete this question due to it being so wildly off the mark?

Comment: No, it's ok, to make mistakes. I prefer a question where the OP made efforts, than a question asking "can you solve it for me".

Comment: Ok, I'm going to get back to work then, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(a,b)\in(\ell_0)^2\ $ let's define $\ d(a,b)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-b_n|$

Also let's have $N(a)=\inf\{ n\in\mathbb N\mid \forall m\gt n, a_m=0\}$, it always exists since sequence in $\ell_0$ are eventually null.

Let's call $M(a,b)=\max(N(a),N(b))$.

- $d(a,b)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{M(a,b)}|a_n-b_n|$ is a finite sum, so it is well defined and positive.
- $d(a,b)=d(b,a)$ is trivially verified since $|a_n-b_n|=|b_n-a_n|$
- $d(a,b)=0\iff\forall\ n\le M(a,b),\ |a_n-b_n|=0$ since it is a sum of positive terms, so for $n\le M(a,b), a_n=b_n$ and for $n>M(a,b), a_n=b_n=0\iff a=b$.
- $|\cdot|$ verifies the triangular inequality, and $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a finite sum, thus linear, so $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ also verifies the triangular inequality.

*Note: you can redact the fourth point in details if you want, but I think it is not necessary.*

> So $d$ is a distance in $\ell_0$.

Let's have $\displaystyle (a_k)_k=\{\frac 1p,\frac 1{p^2},..,\frac 1{p^k},0,0,...\}$ for $k\in\mathbb N^*$ and $p$ prime.

For $n\in\mathbb N,\ N(a_k)=k$ and $N(a_{k+n})=k+n$ so

$\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle d(a_k,a_{k+n})=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty|{a_k}_i-{a_{(k+n)}}_i|=\\
\displaystyle \phantom{d(a_k,a_{k+n})}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k|{a_k}_i-{a_{(k+n)}}_i|+\sum\limits_{i=k+1}^{k+n}|{a_k}_i-{a_{(k+n)}}_i|+\sum\limits_{i=k+1+n}^\infty|{a_k}_i-{a_{(k+n)}}_i|\\
\displaystyle \phantom{d(a_k,a_{k+n})}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k |\frac 1{p^i}-\frac 1{p^i}|+\sum\limits_{i=k+1}^{k+n}|0-\frac 1{p^i}|+\sum\limits_{i=k+1+n}^\infty |0-0|\\
\displaystyle \phantom{d(a_k,a_{k+n})}=\sum\limits_{i=k+1}^{k+n}\frac 1{p^i}=\frac 1{p^{k+1}}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac 1{p^i}=\frac 1{p^{k+1}}\frac{1-{\frac 1p}^n}{1-\frac 1p}\\
\end{array}$

Since $p$ is a prime number $0\le \frac 1p\le\frac 12$ and $\bigg|\frac{1-{\frac 1p}^n}{1-\frac 1p}\bigg|\le 2$

So $\displaystyle d(a_k,a_{k+n})\le \frac 2{p^{k+1}}\to 0$ when $k\to+\infty$ independantly of the $n$ chosen.

> So $(a_k)_k$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(\ell_0,d)$.